# Who is the wife of Prabhas & the mother of Vishwakarma?

Tags: scripture, harivamsa, brihaspati, vasu, vishwakarma

The [Harivamsha](https://archive.org/stream/TheMahabharata_201707/TheMahabharata_djvu.txt) states that Brihaspati’s sister was a beautiful lady who became the wife of the eighth Vasu, Prabhas & Vishvakarma was born from her!

> Brihaspati’s sister was a beautiful lady who practised brahmacharya. She became successful through yoga and roamed around the entire universe, bereft of attachment. She became the wife of the eighth Vasu, Prabhasa. The immensely fortunate Prajapati Vishvakarma was born from her.

Remembering another story, Prabhas was also the Vasu who got cursed by Vasishth to be born on earth because of his wife's insistence on him stealing the Brahmarishi's cow so this lady could be the one behind that prank.

So my question is - **Who is this lady & is she really the mother of Vishwakarma?**

Comment: Yes. Chapter 15, Part 1 of Vishnu Purana also mentions the same information.

Comment: Good to find a corroboration. Now I really wanna know who this lady was!

Comment: Vatstree the sister of Brihaspati is the wife of Prabhas, It is mentioned in Vishnu Puran

Comment: Can you please share the link to the original scripture and post it as an answer?

Comment: Exactly same description  also can be found in Vayu Purana - Uttar Bhaga - Chapter 22 - Shloka No. 15-16. It's written over there that her name was "YogSiddha". Not much other description is there in that chapter.

Comment: Bhagavatam names her AngIrasI meaning the daughter of Angirasa rishi and names her the mother of Vishwakarma.

Comment: @NogShine can you share the verse?

Comment: "vāstor āṅgirasī-putro viśvakarmākṛtī-patiḥ" From Āṅgirasī, the wife of the Vasu named Vāstu, was born the great architect Viśvakarmā. Viśvakarmā became the husband of Ākṛtī Bhagavatam 6.6.15. This also states Chakshusha manu was born from Vishvakarma.

Comment: Awesome.. would be great if you can share it as an answer with the reference. Angiras rishi is the father of Brihaspati so this ties up quite neatly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This chapter](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp050.htm) Vishnu Purana calls her Yogasiddha:

> The sister of Váchaspati, lovely and virtuous, Yogasiddhá, who pervades the whole world without being devoted to it, was the wife of Prabhása, the eighth of the Vasus, and bore to him the patriarch Viswakarmá, the author of a thousand arts, the mechanist of the gods, the fabricator of all ornaments, the chief of artists, the constructor of the self-moving chariots of the deities, and by whose skill men obtain subsistence.

The part about pervading the world is connected to Vedic hymns like [this one](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe42/av068.htm) that describe the wife of Dyaus Pita/Prabhasa as Prithvi or Earth.  (I'm not sure how it relates with Bhudevi being a wife of Vishnu.) And Vachaspati is another name for Brihaspati.

[This chapter](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/6/6/15) of the Srimad Bhagavatam calls her Angirasi:

> From Āṅgirasī, the wife of the Vasu named Vāstu, was born the great architect Viśvakarmā.

Angirasi denotes that she is the daughter of Angirasa, the father of Brihaspati.  And Vastu is yet another name for Dyaus Pita/Prabhasa.

Comment: Fabulous thanks for sharing. This particular lady may be involved in the Kamdhenu-stealing episode then?

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal Yeah, this chapter of the Adi Parva of the Mahabharata describes Dyaus Pita's wife as the one who wanted the cow: http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01100.htm But it doesn't mention her name.

Comment: One more thing although I take it for granted most of the times but any reason whywe equate Prabhas with Dyaus?